# How to display image with zoom effect

Tags: flutter

I have an original image like this, I want to display the image into an image widget on flutter UI, with a zoom center effect.

[image: original image]

And I want the image widget display center and focus zoom in the center of the original image.
I used boxfit but don't have options for something like I wanted, I also use transform matrix scale, but it scales all the image widget, not the image content.

[image]

Please help me how to achieve it, thank you.

**update 1:**

I've used the code to achieve above requirement, but I don't know if anyone have better solution. My steps are transform scale with Transform.scale, then ClipRect the zoom to get the center.

```
int height = 250;
int zoom = 3;

return ClipRect(
      child: OptimizedCacheImage(
        imageUrl: imgUrl,
        useScaleCacheManager: false,
        filterQuality: FilterQuality.medium,
        height: height,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Transform.scale(
            scale: zoom,
            child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                image: imageProvider,
              ),
            ))),
        placeholder: (context, url) => SizedBox(height: height),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong - You have a large image & you just want to display the black border part of this large image, right?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view#:~:text=A%20simple%20zoomable%20image%2Fcontent,Container%2C%20Text%20or%20a%20SVG.

Comment: Just use this [zoom](https://pub.dev/packages/zoom_widget)

Comment: @RaviSinghLodhi yes, i want to display thumbnail of the large image, but the thumbnail will zoom and crop center of the large image.

zoom and photo_view could do it, but I want a simpler solution, I have a list of thumbnail will display like that.

Comment: Talking about transform, you may use a ClipRect to hide those parts that are not used